# Get Twitter relevant/famous hashtags from a sentence

Tags: twitter, hashtag

I am wondering if there is an API which allows to get relevant/famous hashtags from a sentence. For instance, given the following sentence : "Apple released the iPhone 7", it returns both `#Apple` and `#iPhone`.